# How to make all database changes follow UTC timezone?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, datetime, laravel-5, utc

I'm using Laravel 5.5 with MySQL all hosted on AWS.

I set timezone to be UTC in `app.php` also the time in server is `UTC` when I run the `date` command.

However, when I delete a model object from the app's dashboard, the `updated_at` is set to the time of my computer instead of UTC. That said, the `deleted_at` is set to UTC! it's just the `updated_at` I have issue with.

This is the code the deletes the object in Laravel:

```
/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param $eventId
 *
 * @return Response
 *
 * @internal param int $id
 */
public function destroy( $eventId ) {
    $this->eventsService->dashboard->delete( $eventId );
    flash( 'Event has been deleted', 'success' );
    if ( str_contains( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'events/' . $eventId . '/edit' ) ) {
        return redirect( '/events' );
    }

    return redirect( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
}
```

This is from `app.php`:

```
'timezone'        => 'UTC',
```

This is when I run `date` on server:

```
Tue Aug 21 04:48:42 UTC 2018
```

This is a scheduled job that updated the status of events (The app is for travel experiences) from `future` to `current` ...etc, it uses the `Carbon` package:

```
$schedule->command(EventsUpdateStatus::class)->everyMinute();
```

When I run: `SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;` on the DB it says: `UTC`.

What else to check to ensure `updated_at` follows UTC?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change MySql global parameters for set default timezone

look into below link

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20217/mysql-set-utc-time-as-default-timestamp